# Does C++11 std::atomic guarantee mutual exclusion as well as sequential consistency?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I believe the answer is yes, much like in Java.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

If I need to just use mutual exclusion, I can use `std::mutex` and others.

What if I need just sequential consistency and not mutual exclusion? What can be used for that?

Comment: The phrase "mutual exclusion" doesn't really make sense in the context of an atomic variable: if all the accesses are atomic, there's no need to provide mutually exclusive access.

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- see `std::atomic` with `memory_order_seq_cst` for sequential consistency.

Comment: But that would also provide mutual exclusion, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Lazer: It's (at least normally) implemented as a memory fence.

Comment: FYI, Herb Sutter gave a nice talk on the topic in 2012 (http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2).  In it he explains the implementations on common hardware, including why full fences are often required due to hardware limitations.  ARMv8 is supposed to allow lighter constructs.

Answer (score 0):

The individual operations performed on objects of type `std::atomic<whatever>` are atomic, but that's as far as it goes.  So `std::atomic<int>::fetch_add()` is atomic.  But

```
std::atomic<int> x;
...
int tmp = x.load();
tmp += 1;
x.store(tmp);
```

Is just sequentially consistent, not atomic.